# Switch box:multiple switch boxes are not working in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one switch button which works fine. But when I go for more number of switch buttons, the functionality is not working. If I click on the second one, the first switch gets moved from on to off or off to on

Here is my with css and Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   .onoffswitch {
       position: relative; width: 90px;
       -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
   }
   .onoffswitch-checkbox {
       display: none;
   }
   .onoffswitch-label {
       display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
       border: 2px solid #E6E6E6; border-radius: 50px;
   }
   .onoffswitch-inner {
       display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
       transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
   }
   .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
       display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 36px; padding: 0; line-height: 36px;
       font-size: 16px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .onoffswitch-inner:before {
       content: "YES";
       padding-left: 13px;
       background-color: #61A1E1; color: #FFFFFF;
   }
   .onoffswitch-inner:after {
       content: "NO";
       padding-right: 13px;
       background-color: #F01F1F; color: #FFFFFF;
       text-align: right;
   }
   .onoffswitch-switch {
       display: block; width: 27px; margin: 4.5px;
       background: #FFFFFF;
       position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
       right: 50px;
       border: 2px solid #E6E6E6; border-radius: 50px;
       transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
   }
   .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
       margin-left: 0;
   }
   .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
       right: 0px; 
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="onoffswitch">
       <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
           <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
           <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="onoffswitch">
       <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
           <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
           <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want it to be worked for the switch buttons separately. I am not getting where I am going wrong.

Please help me out with this.

Many thanks in advance

[working jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SkRN9/27/)

In the demo fiddle when I click on the second switch button the first one is moving.

Comment: Are you looking for a 100% CSS answer or would a mix of CSS and jquery work for you? - As you could use jquery to add and remove your animation class that moves it from yes to no when the user `clicks on this`

Comment: @Andrew,thanks for response ,I am looking for 100% css if not possible then mix combination is also ok

Answer (score 1):

Both elements need to have different ids to make it work. Please see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mileandra/SkRN9/30/

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
       <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked="checked" />
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
           <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
           <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="onoffswitch">
       <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" checked="checked" />
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
           <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
           <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i tried with the similar approach but i don't know were i went wrong any way thanks for the answer it is working now.